# Compiling Qt 4.5.0 without QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt4, qmake, qstring

For refactoring an existing project with some older code, I need to compile Qt 4.5.0 as static library, on Windows using the MSVC v143 compiler (Visual Studio 2022).

I'm using `configure.exe -static -release` to generate the NMake files.

It seems that by default, it defines the macro `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII`, which disables the constructors `QString(const char*)`, breaking the code that uses it.
The define for `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` appears in the `Makefile.Release` file that `configure.exe` generates.
It seems that there is no option to disable this macro, only one to add additional macros (from `configure.exe -help`).

Is there a way to compile it as static release library without this, or some other workaround?

Comment: Are you really using Qt 4.5? That's 15 years old. Anyway, the best solution is to avoid using the QString(const char*) constructor. They constantly warn against it, but still allow it for some reason. [Here](https://wiki.qt.io/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt) is info from their wiki.